# I'm creating a sound effects pack

Tags: sound-effects, sound-libraries, sound-effects-recording, library-sound-effects

For my Masters final project I am creating a sample pack of car sounds. I've been making test recordings and taking advice wherever I  can get it - there are some very friendly and helpful people about!
As part of the project I've put together a Market research survey to find out what people want and expect from a sample library.

I wondered if you guys might have the time (5 mins) to help me with my survey. To thank you for your help I am planning on holding a draw to win the sample pack once it has been completed.

Here's the link: http://tinyurl.com/sfxsurvey

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance everyone!
Rich.

---

Thanks again to everyone who took part in the survey. I have published a summary of the results on my website at http://rsaudiostore.com/survey-results/ . The market research led to me recording a Renault Clio in the end. You can hear clips from the final sample pack (and buy it :-) ) from the website too.
Thank so much for your help.

Rich.

Comment: filled one in! Interesting questions, really made me think about 5.1/7.1 surround samples too, as I think people would buy these more, especially if recorded well with 5.1 mics.

Comment: I've had quite a few responses from SSD, thanks to you all - please keep them coming!

Comment: great survey - just filled it in - got me thinking about my sound needs and requirements -

Comment: Nicely done. Some interesting questions. All done!

Comment: I can't thank you guys enough for taking part, it's a real help. All of the extra comments are great too!
If you haven't taken the survey already, it really is interesting to hear your opinions!
Thanks again,
Rich.

Comment: I am planning on keeping the survey online for one more week. If you have the time to complete it I'm really interested in your responses. I will publish the (anonymous) results shortly after.. thanks again!

Comment: I've had so many responses its been fantastic! Some quality feedback too.. The survey will be coming offline 6pm this Friday. Thanks everyone.
Rich.

Comment: Did the survey. Really interesting questions